# Primer: Working with E-Mails in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We've setup our Dynamics CRM on-premise with server-side integration with Exchange.

We have generic mail accounts like info@mycompany.com

All those E-Mails go into a Queue in Dynamics.

Now, we'd like to track which e-mails have already been processed by operators and which are still open and need attention.

I've found no documentation how the intended workflow is here. We would could work with a simple status reason but the received E-Mails are already in status "closed" and status reason "received".

How do we empty the queue or how do we track which e-mails have already been handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically everything that you need is on the queue item list. Just go to Service -> Queues and choose the proper queue (you can start with choosing All Items and All Queues or select only the Queue that you described in question). Below you can find by example how this looks like
[image: List of queue items]

The Email that you can see on the screenshot is in fact not simply an email, but a Queue Item - which strictly speaking is a kind of a bag for an entity, which preserves this entity on some Queue. When you select this Queue Item (Email), you can see few options that will help you with your scenario.

1) Route - you can use this to route this item to different Queue (for example you have separate Queue for First Tier Support and separate for Second Tier Support) or User/Team

2) Pick - use this to assign this Queue item to yourself (you will appear in the "Worked By" column. This does not affect the Email itself, it simply indicates the person who is working on the item. By clicking it you can also choose to remove the item from the Queue

3) Release - remove yourself as the person who works on the item, so in fact cancel point 2)

4) Remove - remove item from the Queue (when everything is done). This will not remove Email from CRM, it will simply remove the Email from the Queue, so it will no longer appear on the view (of course you can add this Email back to the Queue anytime)

There is no "proper" way of using this workflow. You have to adapt this to your specific needs. You can have multiple Queues and move items between them, you can remove items from the Queue when they are assigned to the user etc. The simpliest answer to your question - you empty the Queue by clicking "Remove" button on the Queue Item. I think that after some experiments, you will figure out what is the best workflow for you/your company

Comment: Thank you. The menu item for "Queues" was disabled in the menu. This is why I could see the configuration for queues and the e-mails in the queues but I never saw the above menu bar. Now, it is obvious how to handle it.